# Make div responsive and control text alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have the following layout (Parent div, two child divs)

wanted to make this layout responsive for browser's width, so anytime the user changes the browser's width this layout should occupies the same area of screen

also, I wanted to middle-text the content, I've tried `vertical-align: middle;`, `display: table-cell;`

any suggestions?

[Markup here](http://jsfiddle.net/BKtx5/)

[image]

Comment: Look at media queries in CSS.  They allow you to change your css depending on the dimensions of the browser.

Comment: you can use the bootstrap responsive css for this... which uses the @media queries which will help in the responsive design. refer http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/

Answer (score 0):

this is your solution html with css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
    .main{
        width:97%;
        border:1px solid #000;
        height:100px;
        padding:1%;
    }
    .subone{
        width:30%;
        border:1px solid #000;
        float:left;
        height:100px;
        margin-right:2%;
    }
    .subtwo{
        width:67%;
        border:1px solid #000;
        float:left;
        height:100px;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="main">
       <div class="subone">
       </div>
       <div class="subtwo">
       </div>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created you a fluid layout, with your divs. You do not need to use media queries.

And also to use

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

you must put

```
display:table;
```

on the parent div and you must not float the divs inside.

You can check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKtx5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

will it be helpful???

use `diplay:table;` for parent and `display:table-cell` for childs..decalare parents width in percentage with overflow:hidden;

HTML::

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

CSS ::

```
.parent{
display:table;
width:80%;
border-spacing:4px;
border:2px solid black;
overflow:hidden;
}
.first{
text-align:center;
display:table-cell;
border:2px solid black;
width:100px;
height:200px;
}
.second{
text-align:center;
display:table-cell;
border:2px solid black;
height:200px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z5Eze/1/)**